# Android Studio - quickly look up class documentation

Tags: java, android

I am looking for the equivalent of Xcode's option-click (which will popup and show you a definition for the currently selected class). For example, I am trying to lookup all of the methods for EditText. I do see search with Google, but is there a way to see the API directly in Android Studio?

Comment: editTextObj.<cntrl>+<space> or <cntrl>+f12.

Comment: option-spacebar worked as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use `CTRL`+`Q` to see the Javadoc inside Android-Studio when you hover any component. If you wish to enable it upon mouse-hovering, select **Editor Settings** and enable **"Show quick doc on mouse move"**.